# Does bing API provides social media links along with lat/lng - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bing-search

Question title is actually my basic concern , But I wanna tell you that i have tried [Binged](https://rubygems.org/gems/binged) , [rbing](https://rubygems.org/gems/rbing) , [bing-search](https://rubygems.org/gems/bing-search) and [searchbing](https://rubygems.org/gems/searchbing) gems But None of these are working for me . E.g `searchbing` I tried the code below

```
bing_image = Bing.new('your_account_key_goes_here', 10, 'Image')
bing_results = bing_image.search("puffin")
```

The above code result in error below

> JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at  403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

Other gems (mentioned above gave me approximately same kind of error i.e access denied)

Can anyone explain what's going on and where is i'm doing wrong

Comment: Seems your Bing account key is not valid/correct.

Comment: @Mischa I'm using the accout key , is that not correct ?